# Alternative to overleaf: Something where I can directly copy from stackexchange

Tags: overleaf, resources

I write my homework using maths stackexchange while copying to overleaf. But this isn't directly translatable:

1. To do spaces I have to add a `\\`  every  line to do a line break/vertical space/whatever you call it.
2. I can't quite add images and links the same way.

Is there an alternative to overleaf where I can just copy stackexchange directly there?

Comment: which spaces are you needing to do `\ ` often (that sounds like you are doing something wrong, but you have given so little information) overleaf uses standard latex syntax for images. (`\includegraphics`) perhaps you are looking for a local tex installation and something like pandoc that would allow you to write your document in markdown. Or github pages, which would again allow you to use markdown.

Comment: You might want to copy the code from the source code of the question.

Comment: @Gaussler I think the OPs problem is the stackexchange source is markdown plus embeded mathjax and overleaf wants latex. which is why I suggested using pandoc or github pages both of which would let you write the document in markdown +mathjax

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in github i can just copy from stackexchange like even the images and spacing and stuff will the same?

Comment: well the markdown for links and omages is (more or less) the same it doesn't have quite the same fancy gui for uploading images but it's certainly usable, have a look at the sources of a test document such as https://mathml-refresh.github.io/discussion-papers/mjtest  where the markdown git source is https://github.com/mathml-refresh/discussion-papers/blob/main/docs/mjtest.md

Comment: note if you do use latex it is hard to tell from your question which contains expletives but no actual example then perhaps you just want a style with vertical space between paragraphs (common on websites like this, less so in printed documents) in which case just add `\usepackage{parskip}` you should not specify space at the end of every paragraph, just use a blank line.

Comment: THANK YOU. ok so what do i (look up what to) do in github? create a tex file? mathjax file? latex file? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: github (like math stackaexchange) doen't use tex at all so it's more or less off topic here, certainly a tutorial on github flavoured markdown is off topic for a latex site.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks also re `\usepackage{parskip}`. you can post as answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok so what do i look up 'mathjax github' ?

Comment: OK although I honestly couldn't tell if that was an answer (as your question post doesn't really have any problem statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a latex layout that uses vertical space rather than indentation to denote a paragraph then you can add

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

to the standard classes.

Alternatively if you want to really copy stackexchange post source to a document you may prefer a document format that uses markdown rather than latex, eg pandoc or github pages, although the latter is mostly for html generation so online not printed paper.

Comment: Maybe the OP can also benefit from a dedicated keyboard: https://www.theverge.com/2021/9/29/22700522/stack-overflow-macropad-mechanical-keyboard-specs